# Python: replace values when column name contains specific strings

Tags: python, replace

Firstly I want to find a column name that contains 'year/month/day', then replace its values. I was able to do it, but when I assigned it back to the column name that contains 'year/month/day', the error occurs.

```
Wrong Code:
df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('year/month/day')]].squeeze()=df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('year/month/day')]].squeeze().str.replace('year','-').str.replace('month','-').str.replace('day','')
print(df)

Output:
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?

Code without problems by using real column names:
df['birthday_year/month/day']=df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('year/month/day')]].squeeze().str.replace('year','-').str.replace('month','-').str.replace('day','')
```

I only want to assign it back to the column name that contains 'year/month/day', but not the 'birthday_year/month/day'. Any suggestion?

df:

```
  birthday_year/month/day   name
  2023year5month2day        Jack
  2019year6month29day       Lauren
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut instinct is to define the columns you want to operate on and then iterate through them. Then I would write the string manipulations as a lambda function and use the map method of the dataframe object to create a new series to assign as a column in your dataframe.

something like

```
desired_columns = [str(x) for x in df.columns if 'year/month/day' in str(x)]
for colname in desired_columns:
    df[colname] = df[colname].map(lambda a: a.replace('year', '-').replace('month', '-').replace('day', '-'))
```